# firewalld had been disabled but it still show the iptables rules

Tags: iptables, firewalld

The os is centos7.2 and firewalld versions is 0.4.3.2
And I disabled the firewalld.service

```
[root@controller ~]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2017-03-30 23:17:24 CST; 17s ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 3417 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Mar 30 23:15:22 controller.datall.cn systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Mar 30 23:15:23 controller.datall.cn systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Mar 30 23:17:24 controller.datall.cn systemd[1]: firewalld.service: main process exited, code=kil...ILL
Mar 30 23:17:24 controller.datall.cn systemd[1]: Unit firewalld.service entered failed state.
Mar 30 23:17:24 controller.datall.cn systemd[1]: firewalld.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@controller ~]# ps aux  | grep firewalld
root       3640  0.0  0.0 112644   952 pts/0    S+   23:17   0:00 grep --color=auto firewalld
```

and then iptabes-save command still shows some rules like below.

```
[root@controller ~]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [359:27396]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [311:43588]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [422:37323]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [311:43588]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [166:15197]
:INPUT ACCEPT [166:15197]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [118:24382]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [118:24382]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [24:2833]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5:348]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5:348]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [118:24382]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:FWDI_public - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_log - [0:0]
:FWDO_public - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_log - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:IN_public - [0:0]
:IN_public_allow - [0:0]
:IN_public_deny - [0:0]
:IN_public_log - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Mar 30 23:19:22 2017
```

all the iptables services had been disabled. I'm really confuesd now. Who can tell me why?

```
[root@controller ~]# systemctl list-unit-files | egrep 'firewalld|table'
ebtables.service                           disabled
firewalld.service                          disabled
ip6tables.service                          disabled
iptables.service                           disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Firewalld is just a daemon for managing the filtering rules. The filtering itself is done in the kernel using rules that are loaded into the kernel from user space. The filtering does not require an active process running; if the rules are loaded, the kernel does the filtering even if firewalld has been killed.

Comment: how can i clear all the loaded rules?

Comment: You can manipulate the rules with the `iptables` utility. `iptables -F` flushes all chains. See [Flush All Rules, Delete All Chains, and Accept All](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-list-and-delete-iptables-firewall-rules) for more details.